# Measure set that intersects everything

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exists a subset $X$ of $[0, 1]$ with (Lebesgue) measure $0 < \epsilon << 1$ such that for any open set $O$, $\mu(O \cap X) > 0$?

Comment: Perhaps try something like around each rational $p/q$ in lowest terms, the ball of radius $q^{-k}$.  By choosing $k$ large enough, the measure is sufficiently small.  But every open set contains rationals, so the intersection will be an open interval.

Comment: @MichaelBurr what you said works, except you have to ignore $0,1$ since those have $q=1$ and taking $k$ large doesn't help.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oops! I got confused by the title, which just said "intersects everything"; didn't notice that farther down he changed it to "intersects everything in a set of positive measure".

Comment: You wrote "any open set $O$" but I'm sure you meant "any nonempty open set $O$".

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon\gt0$. Since $\mathbb Q$ has measure zero, there is an open set $X$ such that $\mathbb Q\subseteq X$ and $\mu(X)\lt\epsilon$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense, $X$ is a dense open set. If $O$ is any nonempty open set, then $O\cap X$ is a nonempty open set, therefore $\mu(O\cap X)\gt0$.

(You wrote "any open set $O$" but you must have meant "any nonempty open set $O$".)